# Matplotlib 3D plot colors from different classes from Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization

I am trying to plot a 3D plot in Matplotlib from a Pointcloud data which is essentially extracted from two different classes.

However, I cannot differentiate the classes into different colors. My code is below.

```
x=pd.DataFrame(np.array(x).reshape(-1,1))
y=pd.DataFrame( np.array(y).reshape( -1, 1 ) )
z=pd.DataFrame(np.array(z).reshape(-1,1))
target=pd.DataFrame(np.array(target).reshape(-1,1))
new_data=[x,y,z,target]

new_data = pd.concat(new_data, axis=1, ignore_index=True )

new_data.columns = ['x','y','z','target']


colors=[]

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
ax=fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')
ax.scatter(new_data.x,new_data.y,new_data.z,color='target')
```

The color argument cannot be linked to the class in the "Target" column in my dataframe. Is there something that I am missing?[image: My 3D plot with no class differentiation]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer myself- Mapped the Dataframe to the arguments of Color using below `col=new_data['target'].map({'Variable1':'r','Variable2 ':'g','Variable3':'b'})`

Comment: Thanks, I think the new version changed the param input, this one worked for me:
`c=new_data['target'].map({'Clas1':'r','Clas2':'g','Clas3':'b'})`

Answer (score 2):

you're saying that the colors should come from the values of the string 'target'. Change it to `c=new_data.target`

Comment: I guess it was a question because the values in the dataframe- Target included multiple classes which are not directly linked to the color arguments. I solved it by mapping it using the following.   `col=new_data['target'].map({'China':'r','Caucasian':'g'})`